# Simplifying a differential equation using a substitution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following differential equation is given:

$$y'=\ln{\frac{x^3+y}{x}}+\frac{x^3+y}{x}-3x^2$$

I need to simplify this to an ODE that's solvable through quadrature methods. An obvious choice that came to my mind is $\frac{x^3+y}{x}=t$, where $t$ is function of $x$. Using the substitution we get:

$$y'=-3x^2+t'x+t$$

So our equation becomes:

$$-3x^2+t'x+t=\ln{t}+t-3x^2 \iff t'x=\ln{t}$$

So we get $$\int{\frac{dt}{\ln{t}}}=\int{\frac{dx}{x}}$$

The integral on the left is not elementary... Is there another substitution I am missing or perhaps I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: If an antiderivative is not elementary, then a change of variables is not going to change that.

Comment: Not an elementary function in the solution https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3D%5Cln%7B%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E3%2By%7D%7Bx%7D%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E3%2By%7D%7Bx%7D-3x%5E2

Comment: Yeah, everything seems to be correct since $\int{\frac{dt}{\ln{t}}}=Li(t)$. The problem literally stated that the solution is elementary function so I was confused when it didn't end up being one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the antiderivative is non-elementary, performing a change of variables cannot produce an elementary solution.

The last integral that you found is the [logarithmic integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function). Therefore

$$\int{\frac{dt}{\ln{t}}}=\int{\frac{dx}{x}}$$

reduces to

$$\operatorname{li}(t)=\ln|x|+C$$

which after the change of variables $t=\frac{x^3+y}{x}$ forms

$$\operatorname{li}\left(\frac{x^3+y}{x}\right)-\ln|x|=C$$

A symbolic library such as [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) has both [quadrature](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/integrals/quadrature.html) and the [logarithmic integral](https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/mpmath/functions/expintegrals.html#mpmath.li).